# Efficiently unpack a vector into binary matrix Octave

Tags: matrix, vector, binary, octave

On Octave I'm trying to unpack a vector in the format:

```
y = [ 1  
      2  
      4  
      1 
      3 ]
```

I want to return a matrix of dimension ( rows(y) x max value(y) ), where for each row I have a 1 in the column of the original digits value, and a zero everywhere else, i.e. for the example above

```
y01 = [ 1 0 0 0
        0 1 0 0
        0 0 0 1
        1 0 0 0
        0 0 1 0 ]
```

so far I have

```
y01 = zeros( m, num_labels );
for i = 1:m
    for j = 1:num_labels
        y01(i,j) = (y(i) == j);
    end
end
```

which works, but is going get slow for bigger matrices, and seems inefficient because it is cycling through every single value even though the majority aren't changing.

I found this for R on [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25271353/cleaner-way-of-constructing-binary-matrix-from-vector):

```
f3 <- function(vec) {
    U <- sort(unique(vec))
    M <- matrix(0, nrow = length(vec), 
          ncol = length(U), 
          dimnames = list(NULL, U))
    M[cbind(seq_len(length(vec)), match(vec, U))] <- 1L
    M
}
```

but I don't know R and I'm not sure if/how the solution ports to octave.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a sparse matrix (which also saves a lot of memory) which can be used in further calculations as usual:

```
y = [1; 2; 4; 1; 3]
y01 = sparse (1:rows (y), y, 1)
```

if you really want a full matrix then use "full":

```
full (y01)
ans =
1   0   0   0
0   1   0   0
0   0   0   1
1   0   0   0
0   0   1   0
```

Answer (score 1):

Sparse is a more efficient way to do this when the matrix is big.
If your dimension of the result is not very high, you can try this:

```
y = [1; 2; 4; 1; 3]
I = eye(max(y));
y01 = I(y,:)
```

The result is same as full(sparse(...)).

```
y01 =

   1   0   0   0
   0   1   0   0
   0   0   0   1
   1   0   0   0
   0   0   1   0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
% Vector y to Matrix Y
Y = zeros(m, num_labels);

% Loop through each row
for i = 1:m
    % Use the value of y as an index; set the value matching index to 1
    Y(i,y(i)) = 1;
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is:

```
y = [1; 2; 4; 1; 3]
classes = unique(y)(:)
num_labels = length(classes)
y01=[1:num_labels] == y
```

With the following detailed printout:

```
y =    
   1
   2
   4
   1
   3

classes =    
   1
   2
   3
   4

num_labels =  4
y01 =

  1  0  0  0
  0  1  0  0
  0  0  0  1
  1  0  0  0
  0  0  1  0
```