# how to convert a matrix of values into a binary matrix

Tags: r, matrix

I'd like to convert a matrix of values into a matrix of 'bits'.

I have been looking for solutions and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25271353/cleaner-way-of-constructing-binary-matrix-from-vector), which seems to be part of a solution.
I'll try to explain what I am looking for.
I have a matrix like

```
> x<-matrix(1:20,5,4)
> x
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    6   11   16
[2,]    2    7   12   17
[3,]    3    8   13   18
[4,]    4    9   14   19
[5,]    5   10   15   20
```

which I would like to convert into

```
     1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
  1  1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0  0  1  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0
  2  0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0
  3  0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  1  0  0
  4  0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  1  0
  5  0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0  1  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  1
```

so for each value in the row a "1" in the corresponding column.

If I use

```
> table(sequence(length(x)),t(x))

     1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
  1  1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  2  0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  3  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  4  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0
  5  0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  6  0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  7  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  8  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0
  9  0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  10 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  11 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  12 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0
  13 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  14 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  15 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0
  16 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0
  17 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  18 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  19 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0
  20 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1
```

this is close to what I am looking for, but returns a line for each value.

I would only need to consolidate all values from one row into one row.
Because a

```
> table(x)
x
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 
 1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
```

gives alls values of the whole table, so what do I need to do to get the values per row.

Comment: What if there are two equal integers in the same row?

Comment: That conceptionally not the case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is another option using `table()` function:

```
table(row(x), x)
#   x
#    1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
#  1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0  0  1  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0
#  2 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0
#  3 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  1  0  0
#  4 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  1  0
#  5 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0  1  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  1
```

Answer (score 4):

```
    bit_x = matrix(0, nrow = nrow(x), ncol = max(x))
    for (i in 1:nrow(x)) {bit_x[i,x[i,]] = 1}
```

Answer (score 4):

Let

```
(x <- matrix(c(1, 3), 2, 2))
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    1
[2,]    3    3
```

One approach would be

```
M <- matrix(0, nrow(x), max(x))
M[cbind(c(row(x)), c(x))] <- 1
M
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    1    0    0
# [2,]    0    0    1
```

In one line:

```
replace(matrix(0, nrow(x), max(x)), cbind(c(row(x)), c(x)), 1).
```

Following your approach, and similarly to @Psidom's suggestion:

```
table(rep(1:nrow(x), ncol(x)), x)
#    x
#     1 3
#   1 2 0
#   2 0 2
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use the *reshape2* package.

```
library(reshape2)
# At first we make the matrix you provided 
x <- matrix(1:20, 5, 4)
# then melt it based on first column
da <- melt(x, id.var = 1)
# then cast it
dat <- dcast(da, Var1 ~ value, fill = 0, fun.aggregate = length)
```

which gives us this

```
  Var1 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
1    1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0  0  1  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0
2    2 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0
3    3 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  1  0  0
4    4 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  1  0
5    5 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0  1  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  1
```